# On relational theory from "SQL and Relational Theory" by C. J. Date

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I am stuck at one point of the book "SQL and Relational Theory", which pertains to the types that relational attributes can take. The question is this:

> *There are exceptions to the rule that relational attributes can be of any type whatsoever, of which one is that if a relation R is of type
>   T, then attributes of R cannot themselves be of type T.*

Why? Is it because the relation R will be of a type 'Relation [name]', and so attributes cannot be of this type?

Comment: It is the same as in C: a structure cannot contain an instance of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like this:

```
create table address {
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    details address -- the address relation has an attribute that is another of itself
}
```

The *definition* would recurse infinitely.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the late recognition.

Comment: Done!

[This string is just to raise the count of characters in order to successfully add the preceding comment!]

Answer (score 1):

It's because defining such a relation would instantly create an infinite recursion, even before you try to put any data into it.  A relation's heading must be finite.

Comment: Thank you. And sincere apologies for the late reply.